# FrescoImageViewer giving unauthorized error

Tags: android, gradle, fresco

I am trying to use this library **FrescoImageViewer** in one of my android projects. But each time i try to build my gradle after adding the dependency it gives me 401 error.

Dependency i'm trying to add:

> compile 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'

Error i'm getting

`Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/stfalcon/frescoimageviewer/0.5.0/frescoimageviewer-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized`

Any help will be apriciated. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after searching a while.

```
repositories {
    //.... other repos
    jcenter()
}
```

Must add `jcenter()` in repositories in build.gradle file